# Need help creating mongoose query for special purposes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I got some problems with a certain mongoose query.

Imaging having a schema like so

```
var Task = new Schema({
           title: String,
           createdBy: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'
           },
           pool: [{
                   userId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
                   accepted: {
                              type: Boolean,
                              default: false
                   }
           }]
        });

Task.find({pool: {$elemMatch:{userId: userId, accepted: false}}}, {'pool.$':1}).populate('createdBy', '_id name surname').populate('pool.userId', '_id name surname').exec(function(err, tasks){
```

So now the thing is I really just get the array entry I want but i don't get the rest of the Document like title and createdBy.

Anyone any suggestions how to solve this?

Kind regards Thomas

Oh sorry my bad I don't have the keyword var in my schema. I was in such a hurry creating my question. So here again. I am using elemMatch to find a document by a criteria found in an Array. It works very well returning just the found array element. What I want thou is that it returns the whole document like 'title and createdBy and pool' but in pool just the one element matching the elemMatch criteria.

I hope my question is now more understandable.

Kind regards and thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Remove the keyword var from title and createdBy.

Reason: Schema takes a JavaScript object as parameter and in defining a javaScript object, var should not be used in the properties.

```js
//This is correct
{
  prop: "Something"
}


//This is not
{
 var prop: "Something" 
}
```